# Android layout with columns

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a fixed layout with a look like the added picture. GridView, RecyclerView, GridLayoutManager... I just don't get it. I'm not really looking for an answer but more how to think? How can I create a layout that looks like this where I can control the size of the columns, the nr of the columns and backgroundcolor. Later on I will add more functionality like drag & drop functionality to each column.

[image: Android layout with fixed columns and default visual presentation]

My main activity xml looks like this and I still don't get any visible columns in android studio or when I run the app. I must be missing something very vital information about how to plan my layout?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/week_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/lock"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/week_number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/weekdays" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my activity that should match a single column in a recyclerview is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="1dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/weekday">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's a horizontal linear `RecyclerView` with fixed item's width and MATCH_PARENT height